# Merge n amount of objects from array into one array based on id

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, reduce

I'm trying to merge n objects from an array of objects listed below.

I tried to use reduce method, but I can't understand what I'm doing wrong, still new to advance js methods.

```js
  const array = [
    {
      data: {
        '1': {
          foo: 'bar',
          test: true
        },
        '4': {
          foo: 'boor'
        }
      }
    },
    {
      data: {
        '1': {
          x: 'o',
          test2: false
        }
      }
    }
  ];

  const result = Object.values(
    array.reduce((r, { data }) => {
      Object.entries(data).forEach(([id, { ...else }]) => {
        r[id] = r[id] || {
          id,
          fooValue: else.foo, // should be `bar` for id `1` and `boor` for id `4`
          xValue: else.x, // should be `o` for id `1` and `undefined` for id `4`
          all: ...else
        };
      });
      return r;
    }, {})
  );
```

I'm trying to get something like this in a end, but I'm pretty lost.

```
  [
    {
      id: '1',
      fooValue: 'bar',
      xValue: 'o',
      all: {
        foo: 'bar',
        test: true,
        x: 'o',
        test2: false
      }
    },
    {
      id: '4',
      fooValue: 'boor',
      xValue: undefined,
      all: {
        foo: 'boor'
      }
    }
  ]
```

Comment: You've just asked and got answers to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58966177/merge-n-object-from-array-into-one-array-based-on-id

Comment: @Titus yes, but everyone ignoring my edits I even commented under their answers but no1 respond and I can't delete my old question either, so no I didn't get my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const array = [
    {
      data: {
        '1': {
          foo: 'bar',
          test: true
        },
        '4': {
          foo: 'boor'
        }
      }
    },
    {
      data: {
        '1': {
          x: 'o',
          test2: false
        }
      }
    }
  ];
  

let result = Object.values(array.reduce((acc, c) => {
 let list = Object.entries(c.data);
 list.map( o => {
  let key = o[0];
  acc[key] = (acc[key] || {});
  acc[key]['id'] = key;
  acc[key]['fooValue'] = o[1]['foo'];
  acc[key]['xValue'] = o[1]['x'];
  acc[key]['all'] = {...acc[key]['all'], ...o[1]};
     });
 return acc;

}, {}));

console.log(result);

//or 

let result1 = Object.values(array.reduce((acc, c) => {
let list = Object.entries(c.data);
list.map( o => {
 let key = o[0];
 let value = o[1];
 acc[key] = (acc[key] || {});
 acc[key] = {
  id: key,
  fooValue: value['foo'],
  xValue: value['x'],
  all: {...acc[key]['all'], ...o[1]}
 }
 });
return acc;

}, {}));

console.log(result1);
```

Answer (score 0):

*else* is a keyword in Javascript. You cannot use it as a variable. Besides, you should wrap the variable with spread operator with curly braces so as to copy the object

```js
const result = Object.values(
  array.reduce((r, { data }) => {
    Object.entries(data).forEach(([id, rest ]) => {
      r[id] = r[id] || {
        id: id,
        fooValue: rest.foo, 
        xValue: rest.x,
        all: rest
      };
    });
    return r;
  }, {})
);
```

Comment: hmm, `xValue` is undefined for both ids

Comment: also there missing parts in first object under `all`

Comment: Sorry, my answer is incorrect. When the 'or' operator is used, it will return the left expression if the expression is truthy. Thus it never merges the second object with the same ID. It's called short-circuit  evaluation.