# Combine objects to get one single array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, reduce

Got an array to begin with

```
 [
    {
      response: {
        'bab6ffa8-e42e-4daa-a26c-65328503bffc': {
          foo: 'Hello',
          bar: 'World'
        },
        'f1230cf3-9970-4b20-a928-a33c1754620c': {
          foo: 'Hello',
          bar: 'Bye',
          foobar: false
        }
      }
    },
    {
      response: {
          'bab6ffa8-e42e-4daa-a26c-65328503bffc': {
            prod: false
          },
          'f1230cf3-9970-4b20-a928-a33c1754620c': {
            date: 1574462751400
          },
          '3825f180-14ea-4c77-8369-db826751424e': {
            bar: 1.522,
            date: 1574406051700
          }
      }
    }
  ];
```

Well and I'm trying to build array which look like that

```
  [
    {
      id: 'bab6ffa8-e42e-4daa-a26c-65328503bffc',
      fooValue: 'Hello',
      barValue: 'World',
      foobarValue: undefined,
      prodState: false,
      dateNow: undefined
    },
    {
      id: 'f1230cf3-9970-4b20-a928-a33c1754620c',
      fooValue: 'Hello',
      barValue: 'Bye',
      foobarValue: false,
      prodState: undefined,
      dateNow: 1574462751400
    },
    {
      id: '3825f180-14ea-4c77-8369-db826751424e',
      fooValue: undefined,
      barValue: 1.522,
      foobarValue: undefined,
      prodState: undefined,
      dateNow: 1574406051700,
    }
  ]
```

I started coding it

```
  const result = array.map(obj => obj.response);

  console.log('result', result);
```

But it's all I got so far, friend said I can try using `reduce` and more `map`, not sure how to implement that, and he didn't really explained, so that's why I'm here.

I just don't want to use for loops, they are ugly and hard to read.

Comment: Invalid object structure

Comment: @User863 edited

Comment: Similar question asked  yesterday - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58966997/merge-n-amount-of-objects-from-array-into-one-array-based-on-id/58967241#58967241

Comment: @SaurabhYadav question you linked doesn't even have correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use reduce method to iterate through your array and `for in` to iterate through keys of object to add necessary key and their values:

```js
let arr = [
   {
     response: {
       'bab6ffa8-e42e-4daa-a26c-65328503bffc': {
         foo: 'Hello', bar: 'World'
       },
       'f1230cf3-9970-4b20-a928-a33c1754620c': {
         foo: 'Hello', bar: 'Bye', foobar: false
       }
     }
   },
   {
     response: {
         'bab6ffa8-e42e-4daa-a26c-65328503bffc': {
           prod: false
         },
         'f1230cf3-9970-4b20-a928-a33c1754620c': {
           date: 1574462751400
         },
         '3825f180-14ea-4c77-8369-db826751424e': {
           bar: 1.522, date: 1574406051700
         }
     }
   }
 ];    

 const result = arr.reduce((a,c) => {
    for (const key in c.response) {
      a[key] = a[key] || { id: key, bar: c.response[key].bar };
      for (const respKey in c.response[key]) {
         a[key][respKey] = c.response[key][respKey];
      }
    }

    return a;
 }, {})

 console.log(Object.values(result));
```

**UPDATE 1:**

If you want to add explicitly keys, then just add them into this expression:

```
a[key] = a[key] || { id: key, bar: c.response[key].bar, 
    foobarValue: c.response[key].foobarValue };
```

Let me show an example:

```js
let arr = [
   {
 response: {
   'bab6ffa8-e42e-4daa-a26c-65328503bffc': {
     foo: 'Hello', bar: 'World'
   },
   'f1230cf3-9970-4b20-a928-a33c1754620c': {
     foo: 'Hello', bar: 'Bye', foobar: false
   }
 }
   },
   {
 response: {
     'bab6ffa8-e42e-4daa-a26c-65328503bffc': {
       prod: false
     },
     'f1230cf3-9970-4b20-a928-a33c1754620c': {
       date: 1574462751400
     },
     '3825f180-14ea-4c77-8369-db826751424e': {
       bar: 1.522, date: 1574406051700
     }
 }
   }
 ];

 const result = arr.reduce((a,c) => {
for (const key in c.response) {
  a[key] = a[key] || { id: key, bar: c.response[key].bar, foobarValue: c.response[key].foobarValue };
  for (const respKey in c.response[key]) {
        a[key][respKey] = c.response[key][respKey];
  }
}

return a;
 }, {})

 console.log(Object.values(result));
```

Comment: Can you explain what's a purpose of second loop? I'm struggling to understand it

Comment: One thing, can I make it so it won't add keys unless they specifically included, like `id` and `bar` in your answer and only them.

Comment: sorry I wasn't clear, I meant I want include everything from this line `a[key] = a[key] || { id: key, bar: c.response[key].bar };`, which is `id` and `bar` in this particular case

Comment: is this possible?

Comment: yeah, I understand how to add keys, I just don't want other keys to be added unless I added them myself for example `{
    id: 'bab6ffa8-e42e-4daa-a26c-65328503bffc',
    bar: 'World',
    foobarValue: undefined,
    foo: 'Hello',
    prod: false
  },` it's added `foo` and `prod` which I don't want. I'm very sorry for bad explanation, don't want to waste your time.

Comment: Stackoverflow suggesting to open chat, but I need 20 reputation points to do so, sorry again :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202866/discussion-between-stepup-and-shaiko).

Answer (score 0):

```js
const list = [
   {
     response: {
       'bab6ffa8-e42e-4daa-a26c-65328503bffc': {
         foo: 'Hello', bar: 'World'
       },
       'f1230cf3-9970-4b20-a928-a33c1754620c': {
         foo: 'Hello', bar: 'Bye', foobar: false
       }
     }
   },
   {
     response: {
         'bab6ffa8-e42e-4daa-a26c-65328503bffc': {
           prod: false
         },
         'f1230cf3-9970-4b20-a928-a33c1754620c': {
           date: 1574462751400
         },
         '3825f180-14ea-4c77-8369-db826751424e': {
           bar: 1.522, date: 1574406051700
         }
     }
   }
 ];    

var mapping = {'foo': 'fooValue', 'bar': 'barValue', 'foobar': 'foobarValue', 'prod': 'prodState', 'date': 'dateNow'};
var result = Object.values(list.reduce((acc, {response}) => {
 for(let [key, value ] of (Object.entries(response))) {
  if(!acc.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
   acc[key] = {id: key};
  }
  
  for(let [keyName, valueName] of (Object.entries(mapping))) {
    if(acc[key][valueName] == undefined){
    acc[key][valueName] = value[keyName]
    }
  }
 }
    return acc;
 }, {}));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: `bab6ffa8-e42e-4daa-a26c-65328503bffc` is missing `prod` value, also updated my question

Comment: @Shaiko i remember that this same question asked .. day before ?

Comment: just run your snippet, you will see.

Comment: @SaurabhYadav I am sorry, I've edited your question accidentally:).